# Selectively remove subdirectory structure using wget

Tags: wget

In order to download a page I use the following command:

```
wget -kmnH -p http://www.example.com/my/own/folder/page.htm
```

I get the following directory structure:

```
/js_folder
/css_folder
/my
  /own
    /folder
      page.htm
```

What I need is the following directory structure:

```
/js_folder
/css_folder
/page.htm
```

I tried using `--cut-dirs=3` but it puts all the `js` and `css` in the same folder as `page.htm`.

Is there a way to bypass this problem calling wget only once?

Other solutions are welcome as well!

Comment: I had to do something similar for a project once but I could find no way to do this with wget by itself. Even with arguments of what files to grab onl, etc. What I ended up doing was creating another script that would then sort the files

Comment: @Kyle Did you ask it on SO?

Comment: I don't believe so, I just did a bunch of research and ended up writing a python script to do it. But the same thing could be achieved with a shell script. If you are interested in it, I will be more than happy to give you the code. I just wouldn't be able to give it to you until later tonight.

Comment: @Kyle Ok, no worries... when you can, the question will still be here! :)